# get bitmap pixel in custom view after rotate

Tags: android, math

Below is the goal of my little custom view (custom imageview):

When I click on the custom view, that contains an image (bitmap + matrix), I want to get the pixel and check if the pixel color is transparent or not, then I would do something.

This is my image when the app starts, the black color is the background color of my custom view, my bitmap (the red arrow) has the same size as the imageview, so all the black color is transparent in my bitmap:

[Image when app starts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSgLW.png)

the problem is when I rotate the image using the matrix and then I click on the non-transparent area of my actual view, it prints, on "logcat", that I click on a transparent pixel

this is my image after rotate:

[Image after rotate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIr0O.png)

if I click on the red cross mark position it prints "red" an if I click on blue cross mark position it prints "transparent"

i don't want to use:

```
Bitmap tmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(img, 0, 0, img.width(), img.height(), matrix, true);
```

because I use OnTouchListener and if I use the previous method each time my app  becomes too slow (laggy)

is any other approach to solve my problem (maybe with maths) if someone can help me thank you in advance.

my layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#fff">

    <CustomView
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:background="#000"
        android:scaleType="matrix"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

my custom view (with only useful part of code): **SOLUTION**

```
public class CustomView extends View {

    private Bitmap arrow;

    private RectF viewRect = new RectF();
    private PointF center = new PointF();

    private Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    private Matrix inverted = new Matrix();

    private float angle = Float.NaN;

    private boolean READY = false;


    public CustomView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        init();
    }

    public CustomView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        init();
    }

    private void init(){

        getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {

                if(viewRect.width() == 0 && viewRect.height() == 0) {
                    viewRect = new RectF(0, 0, getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredHeight());
                    center = new PointF(viewRect.width() / 2f, viewRect.height() / 2f);

                    try {
                        InputStream ims = getContext().getAssets().open("imgs/arrow.png");
                        arrow = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(ims);
                        arrow = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(arrow, (int)viewRect.width(), (int)viewRect.height(), true);
                        ims.close();
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        return;
                    }

                    READY = true;

                    setOnTouchListener(new CustomTouchListener());
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        if(READY) {
            canvas.drawBitmap(arrow, matrix, null);
        }
    }

    private class CustomTouchListener implements OnTouchListener{

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            switch (event.getAction()) {

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                    matrix.invert(inverted);
                    float[] pts = {event.getX(), event.getY()};
                    inverted.mapPoints(pts);
                    int x = (int) pts[0];
                    int y = (int) pts[1];
                    return viewRect.contains(x, y) && arrow.getPixel(x, y) != 0;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    float tmpAngle = (float) Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(event.getY() - center.y, event.getX() - center.x));
                    if (Float.isNaN(angle)) angle = tmpAngle;
                    matrix.postRotate(tmpAngle - angle, center.x, center.y);
                    angle = tmpAngle;
                    invalidate();
                    return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: see `Matrix#mapPoints` method

Comment: you dont get color, you get the mapped point instead, the docs say: *"Apply this matrix to the array of 2D points, and write the transformed points back into the array"*

Comment: complicated? one call to `Matrix#mapPoints` is complicated? what have you tried so far?

Comment: it s maybe one call but what give in params (the bitmap coordinate (top,left)) and when call this method?

Comment: call it where you want to test the pixel (in your case `onTouch`)

Comment: ok, so start from here: https://pastebin.com/bmG55aAB

Comment: now, do you know how it works?

Comment: yes thank you for your help, I updated my previous solution(too heavy for simple thing) with your solution

Comment: and what is the reason for custom `OnGlobalLayoutListener` and `OnTouchListener`? why make it harder? why dont you use the code as i posted (with `onSizeChanged` and `onTouchEvent`)? and without `createScaledBitmap` which createss additional extra `Bitmap`?

Comment: in my real class I did other things in OnGlobalLayoutListener and onTouchListener (need ACTION_UP and ACTION_CANCEL) I just past the useful parts and for createScaledBitmap I use setRectToRect but it doesn't rotate from the center, but I will remove OnGlobalLayoutListener and do in thread

Comment: if it does not rotate from the center you have to use an image like [this](https://pasteboard.co/GBZTeQQ.png) where the center of the arrow's circle is in the center of the image

Answer (score 0):

You need to translate click coordinates into rotated system.

```
x' = center.x + (x - center.x) * Cos(angle) - (y - center.y) * Sin(angle)
y' = center.y + (x - center.x) * Sin(angle) + (y - center.y) * Cos(angle)
```

Comment: This is rotation about center. Perhaps you have to change angle sign.

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar before which I think might help you. I make use of abs to ensure the value stays positive since we are working with color. I will only add the relevant code

For your custom view, add an OnTouch Listener like this :

```
 @Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
    float xvalue = Math.abs(event.getX());
    float yvalue = Math.abs(event.getY());
    int point = arrow.getPixel((int)xvalue,(int) yvalue);// This will give you the color of the specific pixel on your bitmap.

    //Here you can convert in to RGB
    int red = Color.red(point); // Red value 0-255 of that pixel pixel.
    int green = Color.green(point); // Green value 0-255 of that pixel pixel.
    int blue = Color.blue(point); // Blue value 0-255 of that pixel pixel.

    Log.d("Colours","R:" +red +" G:" + green + " B:" + blue);

    return true;
}
```

Not sure if this will help ? Also, be sure to use

```
invalidate();
```

to refresh your view after you have done your rotation.